# Stegnography Implementation on matlab by using bit operations

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

i am trying to hide an image into another image. For that i first resize the images into equal sizes. and then split out the R, G and B matrices to hide contents into them. I successfully hided the first image into others R,G and B matrices. 
So the Problem is that now i can not concat R,B and G into one image,here is the effort from me.

```
Image1=imread('cameraman.tif');
%imshow(Image1);
Image2=imread('saturn.png');
%imshow(Image2);
%scale=[height,width];
%Resized_image=imresize(Image1,[height,width]);
Resized_image = imresize( Image1,[size(Image2,1) size(Image2,2)]);
%imshow(Image2),figure,imshow(Resized_image);

%converting an image into binary form
Temp=Resized_image;
Temp2=Image2;


%Getting red,blue and green matrices.

im_red = Image2;
im_green = Image2;
im_blue = Image2;

im_red(:,:,2) = 0; 
im_red(:,:,3) = 0;
[x,y] = size(Temp);
%trying to put 2bits into red
for i=1:x
     for j=1:y
         bin = bitshift(im_red(i,j),2);
         first_2_bits = bitshift(Temp(i,j),6);
         oring = bitor(bin,first_2_bits);
         Temp2(i,j) = oring;
     end
end

%green matrix
im_green(:,:,1) = 0; 
im_green(:,:,3) = 0; 
[a,b] = size(Temp);
% t1 = a+x;
% t2 = b+y;
for i=1:a
     for j=1:b
         bin = bitshift(im_green(i,j),2);
         first_2_bits = bitshift(Temp(i,j),6);
         oring = bitor(bin,first_2_bits);
         Temp2(i,j) = oring;
     end
end

%Blue matrix
im_blue(:,:,1) = 0; 
im_blue(:,:,2) = 0;
[c,d] = size(Temp);

for i=1:c
     for j=1:d
         bin = bitshift(im_blue(i,j),2);
         first_2_bits = bitshift(Temp(i,j),6);
         oring = bitor(bin,first_2_bits);
         Temp2(i,j) = oring;
     end
end

img=cat(3,im_red,im_green,im_blue);
imshow(im_red),figure,imshow(im_green),figure,imshow(im_blue),figure,imshow(img);
```

so the error i am getting is unsupported dimension for concatenated image 'img'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you concatenate the images, each individual image must have dimensions `1500x1200` in order that the RGB image has dimensions `1500x1200x3`.

One solution is:

```
img = cat(3,im_red(:,:,1), im_green(:,:,2), im_blue(:,:,3));
```

And another option is:

```
img = im_red + im_green + im_blue;
```